# How to set defaults for ransack sorting?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ransack

To put simply enough, I'd just like to know if there's a way to set defaults for the sorting functionality using the Ransack gem? **ie.**

Currently, I have the following when the page loads:

[image: empty_ransack]

But instead, I'd like to have the following **defaults** when the page loads:

[image: ransack with defaults]

Is it possible to do this via proper configuration of the Ransack Gem?

Thanks in advance as always!

Best Regards!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@search = Change.search(params[:q])
@search.sorts = 'updated_at desc' if @search.sorts.empty?
```

Note: I had some head scratching at first, when I had `desc` in uppercase – that just doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

You can also set multiple default sorts by defining an array:

```
@search = Post.ransack(params[:q])  
@search.sorts = ['name asc', 'created_at desc'] if @search.sorts.empty?
@posts = @search.result.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
```

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Sorting-in-the-Controller